# Match each word in a phrase with another cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there an option to split/divide the phrases in colA and if there a mentioned word that matches the divided word/s in col B it will say "word matched" in col C?

and disregard the plural forms?

[image]

I got this formula: Where it matches both columns. =ArrayFormula(if(len(B3:B)*len(A3:A),IF(regexmatch(lower(B3:B),lower(regexreplace(A3:A," ","|")))=TRUE,"Matched Word","No Match"),)) The problem with this formula is if the column A has some regular plural form of words or the ones with "s"

Answer (score 0):

This gets pretty complicated if you have more than one word in Column B. But if you stick to one word (or one phrase that can't be split) to search for, then you can use the simple `SEARCH` or `FIND` functions.

The formula in `C2` could be:

```
=if(iserror(search(B2,A2)),"No match", "Match")
```

Comment: I got this formula: Where it matches both columns.  

=ArrayFormula(if(len(B3:B)*len(A3:A),IF(regexmatch(lower(B3:B),lower(regexreplace(A3:A," ","|")))=TRUE,"Matched Word","No Match"),))

The problem with this formula is if the column A has some regular plural form of words or the ones with "s"

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(SPLIT(LOWER(B2)," "),LOWER(A2))))),"A Word Matched","No Matched Word")
```